# Multiplying numbers in a list - python list index out of range

Tags: python, list

```
numbers = list(range(100,1000))
possnum = list()

i = 0
multby = 1
while i <= len(numbers):
    possible = numbers[i] * numbers[i + multby]
    possnum.append(possible)
    if multby == 899 - i:
        multby = 1
        i = i + 1
    else:
        multby = multby + 1


print(possnum)
```

I'm trying to make it so all the numbers in the range multiply eachother once. I keep on having an error on this line:

```
possible = numbers[i] * numbers[i + multby]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

I don't understand what I did wrong -- thanks!

Comment: `while len(numbers) > 0:` will loop forever. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think you can try with `while i < len(numbers)-1:` to avoid error. Then, you can verify the result.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are trying to do this

```
numbers = list(range(100,1000))
possnum = list()
for i in numbers:
    numbers.remove(i) 
    for j in numbers:
    possnum.append(i*j)

print (possnum)
```

you approach for iterating over every element is wrong check the index at each iterations

Answer (score 0):

One of your issues is that you are using `while len(numbers) > 0`, which will always be true unless you set `numbers = []` or remove all elements from the `numbers` list.

To achieve your end goal, you should take advantage of the `itertools` module to enumerate all combinations within your list.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

numbers = list(range(100,1000))
possnum = list()

for i, j in combinations_with_replacement(numbers, 2):
    possnum.append(i * j)
```

If you don't want to use `itertools`, the standard way of iterating over a list is to use the `for ... in ...:` construct rather than referencing by index. If you want combinations of all pairs of items in the list, you should use a nested loop:

```
for i in numbers:
    for j in numbers:
        possnum.append(i * j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, sort of obviously, the value of `i + multby` is greater than the maximum index of your array.

At the top of your while loop, print the value of `i + multby` if you need further evidence.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue i found here is you are accesing numbers[len(numbers)] which is not possible as the index range of number is from only 0 to len(numbers)-1.

change the loop condition as follows:
`while i<len(numbers):`